# get info of the data visible in view - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting data from back-end and displaying the data using ng-repeat. I just want to capture the id of all the data displayed in view

ex.

```
Some data 1
```

> ```
> Some data 2
>
> Some data 3
>
> Some data 4
> ```

```
Some data 5

Some data 6
```

Every row will have unique id, I want to get those id which is displayed in view at once.
If there are total 6 rows and 3 rows are visible in the screen then I want the id of that 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-repeat to iterate over a collection of items, what you probably want to is hide them by setting an isVisible property on them and then having AngularJS hide them for you using ng-show. For instance:

```
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="item.isVisible">{{ item.name }} 
            <a href="#" ng-click="hideMe(item)">click to hide</a>
        </li>
```

Where hideMe is defined as:

```
$scope.hideMe = function(item) {
    item.isVisible = false;
};
```

If you then want to know which items are visible and which aren't - you just filter your collection of items on the isVisible property:

```
$scope.getVisibleItems = function() {
    return $scope.items.filter(function(item) { return item.isVisible === true });
```

Here's a fiddle that shows the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/dt1g22mx/2/

Comment: All items are displayed. I am talking about the view. In a view at a time only some rows are visible not all, you have to scroll to see all rows. I want the info of those rows which is displayed in the view

Comment: Ah sorry - I  misunderstood. I would look into https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear - I know it's jquery but I don't have a nice AngularJS solution for you for that right now, sorry. EDIT... although maybe this: https://github.com/L42y/angular-appear